# How do you customize/style codeigniter errors?

Tags: php, codeigniter, xhtml

I'm trying to customize the CSS/HTML for error message displays in codeigniter so I can apply a  tag too each and style them up.

I tried to Google this and search the manual but must have been searching for the wrong terms - can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do something like this...

```
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
```

See the related [Codeigniter documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html)

Note: Updated to correct function reference (validation should be form_validation).

Comment: Thanks, no idea how I missed that... sorry.

Comment: I don't really like, that you have to call this method every time you need to do form validation.

If you want to avoid a duplication, you can sets it globally by this method: http://chris-schmitz.com/changing-default-error-delimiters-in-codeigniter/

Comment: @petrkotek YOU DA MVP THANK YOU

Answer (score 3):

I recommend more elegant way.

Сreated a MY_Form_validation.php file and dropped it into application/libraries with the following code overriding the default delimiters.

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_error_prefix = '<p class="error">';
        $this->_error_suffix = '</p>';
    }
}
```

Link to original: http://chris-schmitz.com/changing-default-error-delimiters-in-codeigniter/

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method "set_error_delimiters" of library "Form Validation":

```
$this->validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
```

Also you can made on code inline with form helper:

```
validation_errors('<div class="error">', '</div>')
```

Or created extends class on form_validation library:

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{
    public function __construct( $rules = array() )
    {
        // applies delimiters set in config file.
        if( ! isset( $rules['error_prefix'] ) )
        {
            $rules['error_prefix'] = '<div class="error">';
        }

        if( ! isset( $rules['error_suffix'] ) )
        {
            $rules['error_suffix'] = '</div>';
        }

        parent::__construct( $rules );
    }
}
```

I like the last method because allow set a style by default and overwrite from before method explain.

Sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
```

This is wrong syntax. the Correct is

```
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
```