# how to print codeigniter form errors from function to html list style

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using form helpers and doing basic validation, I am printing errors using `validation_errors();` function. I want to print them with unordered list. Using the function in foreach as the first argument is it right?

```
echo "<ul>"; 
foreach(validation_errors() as $formErrors)
{ 
echo "<li>" . $formErrors . "</li>";
} 
echo "</ul>";
```

then I receive

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/login.php

Line Number: 23

Backtrace:

File: C:\wamp\www\ci1\application\views\login.php
Line: 23
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\wamp\www\ci1\application\controllers\Main.php
Line: 46
Function: view

File: C:\wamp\www\ci1\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you customize/style codeigniter errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498091/how-do-you-customize-style-codeigniter-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in a manual (did you try to read it?):

> Shows all error messages as a string

So, this function returns string. Which is definitely `invalid` argument for `foreach`.

Reading further, you will find out that function takes two additional arguments, which are the messages delimiters. In your case it should be:

```
echo validation_errors('<li>', '</li>');
```